# SQL protection from creating multiple rows if it is executed twice

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have maybe basic question. Please, could you advise how to create some sort of protection?

As you can see down below.

**If this is executed twice it has to prevent from creating two lines.** 
It should prevent from creating a duplicate. I got this as homework and it is not in my power to solve this. I assume that this is not some hard task but I couldn't find a solution even when I google it.

Thank you for help and understanding.

Here is a code.

```
DECLARE @TEST BIT
DECLARE @Environment VARCHAR(4)
DECLARE @TargetDB VARCHAR(4)
DECLARE @lMailboxID INT
DECLARE @lMailboxAddress VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @lMailServer INT
DECLARE @lStorageFolder INT
DECLARE @lPollingTime INT
DECLARE @lActiveFlag INT
DECLARE @lCustomer VARCHAR(3)
DECLARE @lDomain VARCHAR(32)
DECLARE @lUsername VARCHAR(64)
DECLARE @lPassword VARCHAR(64)
DECLARE @lOperatingMode VARCHAR(15)
DECLARE @lARECode VARCHAR(4)
DECLARE @lOrgID VARCHAR(8)
DECLARE @lProcessFlag VARCHAR(1)
DECLARE @lSetReadFlag VARCHAR(1)
DECLARE @lSenderCheck INT
DECLARE @lDomainCheck VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @lPDFCheck INT
DECLARE @lARECheck INT
DECLARE @lDocPriority INT
DECLARE @lOrgIDCheck INT
DECLARE @lSingleInvoice INT
DECLARE @lMailSourceFolder VARCHAR(32)
DECLARE @lMailMoveToFolder VARCHAR(32)
DECLARE @lFileExt VARCHAR(64)
DECLARE @lPrimaryDocType VARCHAR(6)
DECLARE @lSenderAddress VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @lCockpitDocType VARCHAR(2)
DECLARE @lConfirmTemplate INT
DECLARE @lConfirmAddressCC VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @lVerifRejectTemplate INT
DECLARE @lVerifRejectAddressCC VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @lTechRejectTemplate INT
DECLARE @lTechRejectAddressCC VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @lReducedValidation VARCHAR(1)
DECLARE @lLanguageForReply VARCHAR(2)
DECLARE @lRedirectNoReply VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @lMailReplyTo VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @lServiceName VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @lAttachmentRule INT
DECLARE @DocRejectTemplate varchar(128)
DECLARE @DocRejectAddressCC varchar(128)
DEClARE @ConvertToPDFA bit
DECLARE @AdditionalCustomers varchar(128)
DECLARE @DeleteValidEmail int
DECLARE @DeleteInvalidEmail int 
DECLARE @MessageClass varchar(64)
DECLARE @VerifRescanTemplate varchar(128)
DECLARE @VerifRescanAddressCC VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @RejectionLetterAddress VARCHAR(128)



DECLARE @RECORDCHANGES TABLE (Action VARCHAR(255), Change_what VARCHAR(255),             Change_to VARCHAR(255))

/********************************************************
*              STEP PREPARING VARIABLES                 *
*********************************************************/
SET @TargetDB = CASE @@SERVERNAME
    WHEN 'xyz/xyz'
        THEN 'DEV'
    WHEN 'xyz/xyz'
        THEN 'PROD'
    ELSE 'QA'
    END


IF @Environment <> @TargetDB
BEGIN
PRINT 'PATCH is not applying in right environment'


RETURN
END


/********************************************************
*              STEP CHECK                               *
*********************************************************/

 <<Here I want that code>>

/********************************************************
*              STEP  CHANGING                           *
*********************************************************/
BEGIN TRANSACTION


SELECT @lMailboxID = MailboxID
FROM BW_EC_MAILBOX
WHERE EmailAddress = @lMailboxAddress
AND SourceFolder = @lMailSourceFolder


IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
INSERT INTO BW_EC_MAILBOX (ServerID, EmailAddress, DomainName, UserName, [Password])
VALUES (@lMailServer, @lMailboxAddress, @lDomain, @lUsername, @lPassword)


SET @lMailboxID = @@IDENTITY
END


UPDATE BW_EC_MAILBOX
SET ServerID = @lMailServer
    ,DomainName = @lDomain
    ,UserName = @lUsername
    ,[Password] = @lPassword
    ,SourceFolder = @lMailSourceFolder
    ,MoveToFolder = @lMailMoveToFolder
    ,ProcessFlag = @lProcessFlag
    ,SetReadFlag = @lSetReadFlag
    ,StorageFolder = @lStorageFolder
    ,OperatingMode = @lOperatingMode
    ,FileExt = @lFileExt
    ,PollingTime = @lPollingTime
    ,CheckMailboxAt = getdate()
    ,EnforceOrgIDCheck = @lOrgIDCheck
    ,EnforceARECheck = @lARECheck
    ,SingleInvoicePerEmail = @lSingleInvoice
    ,PrimaryDocType = @lPrimaryDocType
    ,DocPriority = @lDocPriority
    ,CockpitDocType = @lCockpitDocType
    ,Customer = @lCustomer
    ,ARECode = @lARECode
    ,OrgID = @lOrgID
    ,EnforceSenderCheck = @lSenderCheck
    ,EnforcePDFCheck = @lPDFCheck
    ,ConfirmTemplate = @lConfirmTemplate
    ,ConfirmAddressCC = @lConfirmAddressCC
    ,VerifRejectTemplate = @lVerifRejectTemplate
    ,VerifRejectAddressCC = @lVerifRejectAddressCC
    ,TechRejectTemplate = @lTechRejectTemplate
    ,TechRejectAddressCC = @lTechRejectAddressCC
    ,ReducedValidation = @lReducedValidation
    ,LanguageForReply = @lLanguageForReply
    ,RedirectNoReply = @lRedirectNoReply
    ,MailReplyTo = @lMailReplyTo
    ,ServiceName = @lServiceName
    ,AttachmentRule = @lAttachmentRule
    ,DomainCheck = @lDomainCheck
    ,ActiveFlag = @lActiveFlag
    ,DocRejectTemplate = @DocRejectTemplate
    ,DocRejectAddressCC = @DocRejectAddressCC
    ,ConvertToPDFA = @ConvertToPDFA
    ,AdditionalCustomers = @AdditionalCustomers
    ,DeleteValidEmail = @DeleteValidEmail
    ,DeleteInvalidEmail = @DeleteInvalidEmail
    ,MessageClass = @MessageClass
    ,VerifRescanTemplate = @VerifRescanTemplate
    ,VerifRescanAddressCC = @VerifRescanAddressCC
    ,RejectionLetterAddress = @RejectionLetterAddress
WHERE EmailAddress = @lMailboxAddress

SELECT *
FROM @RECORDCHANGES


/********************************************************
*              STEP COMMIT OR ROLLBACK                  *
*********************************************************/
IF @TEST = 1
BEGIN
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION


PRINT 'ROLLBACK'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
COMMIT TRANSACTION


PRINT 'COMMIT'
END
```

I would be very grateful if someone could help me with this.

Comment: You could add a unique constraint to a column or set of columns, after which a duplicate insert would fail.

Comment: As this is homework, I feel uneasy about just doing it for you, so take a read about using IF EXISTS to check if the data you are about to insert already exists.

Comment: Thank you, guys. Could you advise some source that you recommend about SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent duplicate inserts, you can try something on these terms :

```
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
   IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM BW_EC_MAILBOX 
          WHERE ServerID = @lMailServer
            EmailAddress = @lMailboxAddress
            DomainName = @lDomain 
            UserName = @lUsername
            [Password] = @lPassword)
   BEGIN
       INSERT INTO BW_EC_MAILBOX (ServerID, EmailAddress, DomainName, UserName, [Password])
       VALUES (@lMailServer, @lMailboxAddress, @lDomain, @lUsername, @lPassword)
   END
SET @lMailboxID = @@IDENTITY

END
```

Update duplicates won't make any sense, so you only need to take care of inserts.

Comment: I probably didn't express it right. I just wanted some protection like with print "you already execute" if not "ready to execute"

Comment: I see. Then use `IF EXISTS` instead of `IF NOT EXISTS` and inside BEGIN, simple `print "you already executed"`. Hope this make sense ?

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a unique index/constraint.  This is the *right* approach to preventing duplicates, because the database will guarantee the data integrity.  In particular, two inserts happening at the same time cannot insert duplicates.

I'm not sure what you want to be a duplicate, but something like:

```
create unique index unq_bw_ec_mailbox_emailaddress on BW_EC_MAILBOX(EmailAddress);
```

This assumes that `EmailAddress` is unique.  You might want other columns (such as the server or user name) included in the index as well.